# How to obtain Allmusic info from Spotify API?

Tags: api, spotify

Their search API documentation suggests that AMG and MusicBrainz ids/uris come back in the response: https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/web-api/search/

However, the current responses to their example API calls seem to omit this data:
http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track?q=foo

Am I not understanding something correctly, or did they just forget to update their documentation?

I checked their support page and it sent me to stack overflow to ask my question:
https://developer.spotify.com/support/

Answer (score 0):

The ids to AMG and Musicbrainz were there before for the content that was matched (not everything was matched however). Now all ids seem to be missing. You are understanding correctly. The documentation is bad.

Since this is an API question, this is the correct forum.